# Using browser back button to close a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Posting here after doing some research and finding some unanswered questions about this topic.. 
I want to be able to close a modal window when the user clicks the browser 'back' button, this is specially for mobile, since modal windows on mobile tend to take a good portion of the screen, and the user does not have much option other than clicking 'back'..

So, I came across some possible solutions, but haven't fully understood how it can work..

From: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/UKJRM/ it shows very simply how to do this with a link and hash... now the problem is.. when you load a modal window, you don't have a hash link (I'm using jquery bpopup)

So the first part of the question is: how to "append" the hash using only javascript/jquery?

Now the second part of the question would be detecting the back click, cancelling the event and closing the modal.. which I imagine could be something like:

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
    var direction = data.state.direction;
    if ( !! direction) {
        if(direction == 'back'){
            // close the modal
            // remove the hash (how?)
        }
    }
});
```

Can someone please help out?

Comment: What you're looking for is push/pop state.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API